# Select max() of every value mariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that looks like this:

```
name  price  class
a       10     x
a       20     y
a       15     z
b       40     y
b       35     z
c       5      x
c       10     y
c       15     z
c       12     w
```

I want to get for every name which is the highest price and to which class it belongs. something like this:

```
name  price  class
 a     20      y
 b     40      y 
 c     15      z
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT name, max(price), class 
from t 
GROUP by name
```

but it brings me the wrong class. I get this:

```
name  price  class
 a     20      x
 b     40      y 
 c     15      x
```

can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want your output to be if you have two classes that have the same maximum value for a specific name?

Comment: @augustinatossi The results re correct but you are misunderstanding it. You get indeed the max value for that person, but what you are looking for is: give me the full row where the price equals the max price for that name. As illustrated in the answer given by Radu below.

Comment: [_Groupwise Max_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/groupwise-max-in-mariadb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM T
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Name,
                    MAX(price) maxPrice
                FROM t
                GROUP BY Name) tMax on T.Name = tMax.Name
                                           AND T.Price = tMax.maxPrice
```